# jQuery change() event not firing when using .trigger('change')

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code that populates a form when a `select` dropdown value is changed.  On its own it works as expected, but I need to cause this to be triggered when the page is loaded.

I include the parent table in the selector since the `<select>` elements are created dynamically.

As I stated, this works as expected when dropdown selections are made by the user, but the following `$.each` is not triggering the event even though it does iterate through the array and changes the dropdown value - the change event never fires.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var _dropdownVals = [ '-1', '11', '63' ];

    $.each(_dropdownVals, function (val) {
        $('select[name="form_list_0"]').val(val).trigger('change');
    });

    $('table').on('change', 'select[name^="form_list_"]', function () {
        ... do something
    });

});
```

I don't even think the .trigger() should be necessary...

Can anyone tell me why the change event might not be firing?

Comment: You are firing the 'change' event before assigning it.

Comment: @AlanJurczak Yes I was. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is firing, but you haven't registered the event handler yet! Event handlers only handle events triggered after they are registered. Try this instead:

```
$('table').on('change', 'select[name^="form_list_"]', function () {
    ... do something
});

$.each(_dropdownVals, function (val) {
    $('select[name="form_list_0"]').val(val).trigger('change');
});
```

You do, incidentally, need to use `trigger`, because changing values programmatically does not automatically trigger the event.

Comment: This fixes the problem perfectly. I just learned something. Thanks.